# Change the font and background colours of a TMemo in FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, styles, delphi-xe5, firemonkey-fm3

I am writing a memo component that needs to look like an old fashioned terminal session. This should be really simple, but the way FireMonkey styles work seem to make it unbelievably complex.

In a non mobile FireMonkey app I can right click a control and select "Edit Custom Style". This option is not available in mobile apps. Here's the reason given by one of the FireMonkey developers.

> It is support different style on iOS and Android. We cannot run
>   application on Android in iOS style. But when you try to change
>   platform style, automatically we will use it on each target platform.
>   If you want to change default style of fm control, you should put on
>   the form style book and make style in it, or load to stylebook
>   platform style and make changes in it.
>
> Also very important, When you load platform style in style book, You
>   can want that application instance will not have two copy of platform
>   style (one - system in fmx package and other copy in your style book).
>   For it you should to set flag true in TStylebook.UseStyleManager. In
>   this case style in Style book will replace platform style.

OK, so I reckon I need to create a custom style. How do I go about creating a custom style to override only the font and background properties?

I guess I can override the ApplyStyle procedure something like this.

```
procedure TMyMemo.ApplyStyle;
var
  BackgroundObject: TFmxObject;
begin
  inherited;

  BackgroundObject := FindStyleResource('content');

  if Assigned(BackgroundObject) then
  begin
    // Change the background color of the background
  end;
end;
```

How do I know what type the background object is and which property I need to change?

Surely, changing the background colour of a control can't be this difficult! Am I missing something fundamental with the FM styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well one thing I found out is that the fonts can't be changed in FireMonkey! You can set it to a different font but when you run it on a device it will go to the default one.

If you want to change the background color for the memo you should add a stylebook to your form and load a style file you want(Like the default light iOS style). When you have loaded a style go to memostyle and change de background.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

Hope you find useful this workaround

```
uses System.UIConsts;


procedure TfPlanJob.mDetailApplyStyleLookup(Sender: TObject);
var Obj: TFmxObject;
    Rectangle1: TRectangle;
begin    
     Obj := mDetail.FindStyleResource('background');
     if Obj <> nil then
     begin
          TControl(Obj).Margins   := TBounds.Create(TRectF.Create(-1, -1, -1, -1));
          Rectangle1              := TRectangle.Create(Obj);
          Obj.AddObject(Rectangle1);
          Rectangle1.Align        := TAlignLayout.Client;
          Rectangle1.Fill.Color   := claLightslategrey;
          Rectangle1.Stroke.Color := claNull;
          Rectangle1.HitTest      := False;
          Rectangle1.SendToBack;
     end;
end;
```

Comment: and to change the font just go to text settings > font color

Comment: I think you should use instead Margins.Rect := TRectF.Create(...) - or even better just RectF(...) since there's a function for that - to not leak memory, try adding an ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True; to your program (.dpr) file